Error from nuxt-schema-org when I use nuxt 3
I installed the nuxt-schema-org library and used it in nuxt 3 version 3.11.2. However, when I tried yarn dev, this error occurred. Is it because it did not automatically create the necessary files and methods like desire?

The code in my nuxt.config.js is as follows:
    modules: [
      ['@nuxt/image', {}],
      ['nuxt-icons', {}],
      ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', {}],
      ['@nuxtjs/i18n', {}],
      ['@nuxtjs/sitemap', {}],
      // ['nuxt-simple-robots', {}],

      ['@pinia/nuxt', {}],
      [
          '@vee-validate/nuxt',
          {
              autoImports: true,
              componentNames: {
                  Form: 'VForm',
                  Field: 'VField',
                  FieldArray: 'VFieldArray',
                  ErrorMessage: 'VErrorMessage',
              },
          },
      ],
       'nuxt-schema-org',
    ],
    schemaOrg: {
        canonicalHost: process.env.NUXT_DOMAIN_PUBLIC || 'https://example.net',
        defaultLanguage: 'vi', 
        trailingSlash: false, 
      },

Thanks for support ^^
